# Make changes to bundled js/css files

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

When I make changes to my bundled scripts and css files, they do not show when I build and run the project. How do I fix this? I presume I am missing something simple as I am new to C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be some sort of caching issue. Try to clean your browser's cache and load the page again

Comment: Can you post the tags you use to include these files?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the file you are using to include the bundle. You have to delete your cache after making changes especially in edge(any browser really)